# Check both if a textbox is empty and checkbox (un)checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i check both if my textbox is empty and my checkbox (un)checked ?

`.val('')` will only check if my textbox `<input typye="text">` is empty

What will do the trick for empty value each two together (`typye="text" and typye="checkbox"`)?

**EDIT:** my code this that not empty value checkbox, input is include text box and checkbox:

```
newDiv.find('input').each(function () { $(this).removeAttr('checked').val(''); });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty value a check box"? Do you want to deselect it?

Comment: your code works http://jsfiddle.net/ubfGL/

Comment: I use of codeigniter.you see:[example of my code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/insert) please fill text input and checked check box next clicked on link add, see yourself that not work `.removeAttr('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:text').val('');
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

To access checked attribute of the checkbox:

```
var isChecked=$('input:checkbox').attr('checked');
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7WxzC/

Comment: there is no reason to use `:checked` and `attr('checked')` together

Comment: I use of codeigniter.you see:[example of my code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/insert) please fill text input and checked check box next clicked on link add, see yourself that not work `.removeAttr('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//To check whether textbox is empty
if($("input[type=text]").val() == ""){
}

//To check if checkbox is not checked
if(!$("input:checkbox").is(":checked")){
}
```

Comment: I use of codeigniter.you see:[example of my code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/insert) please fill text input and checked check box next clicked on link add, see yourself that not work `.removeAttr('checked')`